# How does mapshaper work to show a shapefile?

Tags: json, mapping, geojson, shapefile, mapshaper

I just want to show my shp / json file as in http://mapshaper.org/ . How can I carry it out?
I want to use similar platform to display my shapefile in web.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop your shapeFile or geoJSON or TopoJSON or DBF or CSV file to https://mapshaper.org/

It will ask option to "detect line intersections" and "snap vertices". Check as per your convenience and import.
your file will be loaded.

Comment: Its not what i asked. I want to make similar platform. Just I need is to display my shapefile in web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and its leaflet library to display geojson files to the web.  Use QGIS or arcmap to convert a shapefile to a geojson file than write some javascript and html code to publish it to a site.  You can use the ajax plugin very easily to display a geojson file onto a web map.  Download plug in here https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax.